# Merging 2 face loops into 1 - Topology

Tags: modeling, edges, topology

So I'm trying to merge two face loops into one like so:

[image]

would it be detrimental to do this using tris? If so is there any way of doing this with quads only? Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tris may or may not be problematic depending on your model :).

These are some ways to reduce two loops into one.
Including 2-level Subdivision, so you can see the resulting geometry.

[image]

Further Reading:
[Topologyguides.com](https://topologyguides.com/post/163679954765/loop-reduction)

Comment: Dangg I'm gonna use that site from now on it's useful af thanks!

Comment: Couldn't say that better myself :).